# Got/Gotten- Is there a trick?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Got/Gotten- Which one should I use and is there a trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotten is American English, got British English.

Comment: In general, I agree with @rogermue.  However, in some varieties of British English, they *do* say 'gotten'.  I hear it around Liverpool, and I've noticed that I use 'got' and 'gotten' randomly  -  whether influenced by Liverpool people or exposure to American speech, I'm not sure.